# How to plot a long trignometric equation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm very new to Matlab, and I keep getting errors even for small things like typing 2pi, etc.

Can someone please tell me how to plot the following graph using Matlab:

1 - 8(cost)^2 + 8(cost)^4

Where 0<=t<=2pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t = linspace(0,2*pi,1000); %# 1000 points
f = 1 - 8*cos(t).^2 + 8*cos(t).^4; %# .^ is for elementwise exponent
plot(t,f)
```

[image: f(t)]

Comment: Give 10 instead of 1000 and observe that `t` and `f` are vectors of size 10 and see their values by typing them on the command line without ending semicolon. 1000 is for better resolution.

Comment: It says that the method "linespace" is undefined. I'm sorry, I'm really new to this. Should I 'import' this method somewhere?

Comment: @user952949: its `linspace` not `linespace` (short for generate linearly spaced points)

Comment: It's `linspace`, not `linespace`. That's "lin" as in "linear". There is also a `logspace`.

Comment: Yes, 1000 specifies the number of equidistant points you want in the range [0, 2*pi]. You can open the Product Help from the Help menu and search for the `linspace` function or type `doc linspace` in the command line.

Answer (score 4):

[fplot](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/fplot.html) is quicker and easier than generating dummy vectors of X and Y points, as it's designed for plotting arbitrary functions rather than actual data:

```
f = @(x)(1-8*cos(x).^2+8*cos(x).^4);
fplot('f',[0 pi*2]);
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks much better than plotting the vectors of x and y; and much more intuitive (like being able to set up the domain)

Comment: @PaulR: you could simply use a function handle as input: `fplot(@(x) 1-8*cos(x).^2+8*cos(x).^4, [0 2*pi])`

Comment: It gives me an error:

"function definitions are not permitted in this context"

Comment: @Amro: yes, that might be more concise, but I was going for simplicity and also considering the possibility that having defined the function it might also be useful in other contexts...

Comment: @user952949: make sure that you have the correct MATLAB prompt when you paste this in, i.e. not the continuation prompt

Comment: @Paul R: I just type it in again, I didn't paste it in

Comment: @user952949: don't type, use copy and paste - that way you won't make simple mistakes

Comment: @user952949: You can write `f = @(x)(1-8*cos(x).^2+8*cos(x).^4);` to create a function that takes an input `x` and returns the statement in the parantheses, then call `fplot(f,[0 pi*2]);`.

Comment: @Ismail: thanks - that's neater than my original version - I'll update the answer to use this

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a vector of value for `t`, for example

```
t = 0:0.01:4*pi;
```

You can then evaluate your expression at each value of `t`, for example

```
y = 1 - 8*cos(t).^2 + 8*cos(t).^4
```

Notice that we used `.^` instead of simple `^`. The dot in this case means that we take each entry of the resulting vector to a power, not the vector itself.

Now, to ploy the equation we use the `plot` command as such:

```
plot(t,y)
xlabel('t');
ylabel('y');
title('Plot of a trigonometric equation')
```

Comment: Ok, so I understood all of that, except the part where you create the vector for 't'.

How does that make sure that t is plotted from 0 to 2pi?

Comment: This means that your building an array of number fro 0 to 2*pi in increments of 0.01.